# QMenu action entry with ampersand shortcut

Tags: c++, qt, shortcut, qmenu, qaction

I tried to set an action in a QMenu with the ampersand shortcut (&) but the shortcut is not rendered. I should have a rendering like the "Help" action with the F11 shortcut.

[image: Window screenshot]

The code:

```cpp
QMenu* filesMenu = ui->menubar->addMenu("&Test");
QAction* ampersandAction = filesMenu->addAction("Ampersand!");
ampersandAction->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Ampersand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and working.
Just press the "Alt" touch while your app is running and your letter will be underlined as you want it to be.

Comment: My goal is to show the ampersand shortcut in the menu like the "Help" action with the F11 shortcut. I have edited my post.

Comment: @Theo it seems the ampersand character is used by QKeySequence as a pattern matcher, which is one of the class behind the scenes for setting shortcuts. You should pick another character than '&' for a shortcut.

Comment: Far too good to give up that idea :'(, thanks for the help!